# Rack Rails : How do I save query string in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I am using Rack middle ware to intercept all requests to my rails app. I am checking for a particular parameter in the query string. If the request has the parameter, I need to extract its value and put it in a database to be processed later. Otherwise I let the normal course of action to continue. Any ideas how to implement it?

P.S : I have done the following already.

1) I can extract the value of my desired parameter through Rack and send it along with the response (For testing purposes only)

2) I have tried created a custom controller and call it from the rack, but I am hitting upon undefined method error everytime.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us code -- we need to know what your middleware methods are like, how you're calling them, how you're calling the controller etc. We also need to know where in the init process your middleware loads